# Can i use operator 2 operators in a If statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators

How can i use 2 operators in a if statement. I have the following method and the MinSaldo cant be lower then 1000 dollar but i cant use 2 operators in a if statement how can i fix this ?

```
public void MinSaldo(double Money)
{
    if (saldo - money < MinSaldo )
    {
        throw new Exception("saldo low ");
    }

    else
    {
        messagebox.show("works");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course. Other question?

Comment: You can concat multiple conditions either with `&&`(and also) or with `||`(or else)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AND/OR (&&/||) logic for multiple condition statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680943/and-or-logic-for-multiple-condition-statements)  10 seconds of searching would be faster than posting here

Comment: Yes you can definitely. You can combine the conditions based on requirement ... like `if (MinSaldo > 1000 && saldo - money < MinSaldo )`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use as many as you want by combining them with the operators: and (`&&`), or (`||`).

In this case

```
public void MinSaldo(double Money)
        {
            if (MinSaldo < 1000 || saldo - money < MinSaldo )
            {

                throw new Exception("saldo low ");

            }

            else
            {
               messagebox.show("works");
            }
        }
```